# Overflow Issues with Tailwind

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a chat like app using tailwind, and I can't seem to get overflow to function properly.

Instead of overflowing, it just stretches the box to fit all the contents.
Please see the code snippet or link below, at line 25 is where the container begins, the top container should span over 5/6 grid rows, and only overflow if the contents exceed the container!

```
<div class="grid h-screen w-screen grid-rows-6 gap-2 bg-neutral-900 p-1">
  <div class="row-span-1 bg-neutral-800">
    <div class="h-full w-full p-1">
      <div class="mt-5">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between px-5 w-full text-white">
          <div>Com</div>
          <div>3dub</div>
          <div>Prof</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row-span-5 bg-neutral-800 p-1">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-6 w-full h-full gap-1 p-1">
        <div class="col-span-1 h-full">
          <div class="h-full w-full p-1 bg-neutral-700">
            <div class="text-white">Nodes</div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-span-5 h-full">
            <div class="h-full w-full p-1 bg-neutral-700">
              <div class="h-full w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-600 p-4">
                <div class="h-full w-full">
                  <div class="grid grid-rows-6 h-full w-full gap-y-1">

                    <div class="row-span-5 w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-500">
                      <div class="h-full w-full min-h-0 rounded-lg bg-neutral-500 p-4">
                        <div class="flex flex-col h-full w-full overflow-y-scroll gap-y-2">
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                          <div class="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-neutral-400 p-4">Chat Msg</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-span-1 w-full rounded-lg bg-neutral-500">
                      <div>Message</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/2G6f2owRqQ

Edit: Included the wrong play.tailwindcss link

Answer (score 0):

You can just add "overflow-hidden" to line 20.

In line 20 your code must be like below:

> `<div class="col-span-5 h-full overflow-hidden">`

And if you change  "overflow-y-scroll" to "overflow-y-auto" in line 28, scrollbar doesn't appear if messages heights don't exceed their parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to resolve your problem. you can [check here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/y2ovKNSKYB)